Man looks out of the window and sees a man kill himself
I can only remember one scene of a (possibly thriller) movie that I would like to watch again. The scene could be described as: 

A man looks out of his apartment window and sees another man at a street corner, just in front of the building. He is standing, looking right at the window. He is not
  young and wears black clothes with a black hat. The man in the street
  was obviously waiting for the resident to watch through the window
  before killing himself with a gun which he fired on his head (edit).

It wasn't the first apparition of this man in the street. He has been tracking him on a long period and at different places. Every time the victim met the killer, he was frightened because he thought this person would kill him, even if he would not. The goal of the "killer" (who finally killed himself) was to make its "victim" become crazy. 

This sounds an awful lot like Seven Psychopaths.
This particular scene is not really related to the larger plot of the movie, but rather functions as a vignette depicting one of the titular seven psychopaths. 

Ahhh, you are amazing! Thank you!

Hah, wanted to answer that but got distracted by the "gun" from the description (which actually was a knife in this movie).

You are right... also I didn't mention that both guys killed themselves! At first the man in the flat, and only then the guy in the street.
